# Make an external monitor from broken MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hardware

I have an early 2011 MacBookPro 13" with a dead motherboard.

I would like to detach the screen and use it as an external monitor.

Has anyone ever done that? Does anyone have information about pins on the video connector which goes from the display to the motherboard?
Any information is welcome :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find anything about that specific mac, but the instructions for doing so are all the same:
[Instructables, old laptop screen monitor conversion](http://instructables.com/id/Old-laptop-screen-into-Monitor/)

 I hope this helps you creating your monitor.